# Destroy Bootstrap Popover with selector option

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

How do you destroy a Bootstrap popover created with a selector option? e.g.

```
$e.popover({
  selector: 'mark',
  trigger: 'hover',
  container: "body",
});
```

If you then call `$e.popover('destroy')` you get an error.

I note that the `Plugin` function called by `popover('destroy')` is as follows:

```
 function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this    = $(this)
      var data     = $this.data('bs.popover')
      var options  = typeof option == 'object' && option
      var selector = options && options.selector

      if (!data && option == 'destroy') return
      if (selector) {
        if (!data) $this.data('bs.popover', (data = {}))
        if (!data[selector]) data[selector] = new Popover(this, options)
      } else {
        if (!data) $this.data('bs.popover',(data = new Popover(this, options)))
      }
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]() /// <<-- THIS ALWAYS FAILS
    })
  }
```

If you call `$e.popover('destroy')` the above line (clearly marked) always fails because it is calling `data['destroy']`, however the data will be an object like `{mark: Popover}`.

It should clearly be calling `data['mark']['destroy']` but it is not immediately clear to me how this is supposed to happen.

One option is to create a string `s = 'destroy'` then add the `selector` property to the string, but it should be apparent that that is not the intended design.

Alternatively, one could call `$e.data('bs.popover').mark.destroy()`, but again I am not sure that's the intended design, and it's not documented anywhere I could find.

Here's a [sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rhLdghw/2/)

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? Even when using your code, I still get `data` being what it should be (what is `data.mark` in your examples).

Comment: @Matt It's Bootstrap 3.3.1

Comment: Ah, I was working on a older version. Seems like a blatant bug in Bootstrap (introduced in this commit; https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/1b3237629a316af41945e20837cf3a332798b264)

Comment: Thanks @Matt - good find. :) Feel free to submit a bug report to twbs and reference this (or let me know and I can submit one). Cheers

Comment: Brian: I've commented on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15168... seems it wasn't a very well thought through change, and breaks a lot of things!

Comment: Very good, thanks @Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt) commented, this is [a Bootstrap bug in 3.3.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15168).